# EpiServer - load block list based on property on each block

Tags: episerver, episerver-7, episerver-8

If I want to load a list of blocks based on a type I know I can do something like the following:

```
var blockType = contentTypeRepository.Load<MyBlock>();
```

But if I want to load the list based on both a type and a property on each block called tag being equal to "A", and at the same time have the list sorted by the property date on each block, how would I do that?

Comment: Sounds like you would need to retrieve all blocks of a specific type, and then filter the result based on the property values. Unless you're using Episerver Find or another search engine, of course?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. EpiServer Find might be added to the solution later on, but at the moment I do not have it available. Was just worried that if we get a lot of blocks of a specific type, which it looks like we will, that it will be slow.